# Replacing an Azure billing account

Tags: azure

I just signed up for an Azure pay-as-you-go subscription using a purpose-specific outlook.com account.

As this *Microsoft ID* account is also the first Global Administrator, I created a new Global Administrator, and want to begin removing the *Microsoft ID*.

While there is plenty of documentation about modifying the billing account properties, I cannot locate any that describes how to add a new billing account (based on the associated tenant) and remove the *Microsoft ID*.

I would be grateful for any guidance on this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this process little bit tricky, To transfer the billing ownership, follow the steps in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer#transfer-billing-ownership-of-an-azure-subscription).

The new owner must have subscription Owner Role.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to verify and attach a domain to your tenant. You can do that with Azure Powershell or the portal.
Then you can change the user principal name. I wouldn't recommend removing the Microsoft id, than can cause a lot of problems.
And it's best practice to have two accounts with only a Microsoft id, in case of emergency, so called break glass accounts.

I checked in my own tenant, and here you can add another billing account
"Cost Management + Billing" >> Cost Management >> Manage Billing Account
[image: manage billing account]

Comment: There is no requirement to attach a domain to a subscription in order to change the billing information.  All that’s required is that the account you’re transferring the billing to is an account in the Entra ID associated with the subscription and has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Yeah but he also wanted to get rid of the Microsoft id, me answering the domain part was targeting against getting rid of Microsoft id

Comment: I was able to generate a request for a user in the directory (who does not have a valid email) without specifying a validated custom domain. Pending requests (and their links) are available to admins for review).

Comment: The MS id is irrelevant.  It only needs another user in the Entra ID to be assigned the permissions.  You can give that account any email address you like for contact purposes.